# runtimewarning while using lagrange interpolation in numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, interpolation, data-analysis

I am trying to implement lagrange interpolation on a time series. My input is in below format which contains two columns datetime and stock value

```
'3/8/2012 16:00:00  32.21'
'3/9/2012 16:00:00  32.16'
'3/12/2012 16:00:00 32.2'
'3/13/2012 16:00:00 Missing_1'
'3/14/2012 16:00:00 32.88'
'3/15/2012 16:00:00 32.94'
'3/16/2012 16:00:00 32.95'
'3/19/2012 16:00:00 32.61'
'3/20/2012 16:00:00 32.15'
'3/21/2012 16:00:00 Missing_2'
'3/22/2012 16:00:00 32.09'
'3/23/2012 16:00:00 32.11'
'3/26/2012 16:00:00 Missing_3'
```

In some of the input cases the stock value is missing, these missing values i am trying to predict using [scipy.interpolate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.lagrange.html)

```
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

for k in a: # a is input list
    x,y = k.split("\t")
    if is_number(y):
        x = datetime.datetime.strptime(x,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        x = time.mktime(x.timetuple())
        y = float(y)
        x_axis.append(x)
        y_axis.append(y)
    else:
        x = datetime.datetime.strptime(x,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        x = time.mktime(x.timetuple())
        unknown_x.append(x)


x = np.array(x_axis)
y = np.array(y_axis)
unknown = np.array(unknown_x)
y_interp=scipy.interpolate.lagrange(x, y)
for k in unknown:
    print y_interp(k)
```

But i am getting runtime warning,

```
/var/ml/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py:728: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
  val = NX.concatenate((zr, a1)) + a2
/var/ml/python/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py:725: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add
  val = a1 + a2
```

Comment: It's not clear what the question is.  However, you can read about how numpy handles numerical exceptions (the cause of your RuntimeWarning), and how to modify that, here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/misc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `x`s from your date conversion result in large values. Inputting those in a (Lagrange) polynomial and then trying to do an interpolation likely results in numerical instable calculations (since, for large `x` to obtain a relatively small `y`, you'll need small coefficients).

In addition, the documentation for [scipy.interpolate.lagrange](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.lagrange.html) warns that the implementation is numerically unstable.

Always normalize your data to some reasonable numbers. You could subtract a certain date; the default uses 1970, unix zero time, which is obviously a bad choice. With your example dates, pick e.g. first of March 2012), or divide by a value somewhere in the middle (1332000000 could be a good value) to get all your values around 1.